# After Magento migration from 1.9.3.2 to 2.2.3 category changes not saving

Tags: migration, magento2

I have migrated magento from 1.9.3.2 to 2.2.3.

I don't have more product but still i am not able to save category changes in magento 2.

After Press Save buttton "You saved the category." message displays but not changes are saved, even category name is not changing.

Please anyone knowing how to resolve this issue then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the code that is not saving?

Comment: i checked with latest magento code. i think the issue is in either URL generate OR in a database tables,